# WPF PropertyChanged in UserControl DependencyProperty not fired every time

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I've been researching for many hours the following situation: I have a xaml defined window that makes use of a usercontrol (ToggleButton) with some dependency properties.

The underlying viewmodel of the window contains some boolean objects that represent the state of devices (on/off) and others represent a request to toggle a device with a true/false flank (a PLC is connected to these and communication works fine).

Hence there are 2 DP's on the usercontrol:

The one to toggle the devices (binding mode OneWayToSource with an *UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit* work fine (indicating to me that basics like shared DataContext is fine and not "disrupted" anywhere).

However the binding indicating the other DP (device state with binding mode OneWay) shows the following symptoms:

1. The (PLC-)device is off (false) before starting the program

   **Result:** The DeviceState property is at the default value of false.
   Set is called the first time when the device is switched on
   (underlying viewmodel object changes to true, reports this via
   PropertyChanged notification) and the DependencyPropertyChanged is
   being called correctly. Further switches to off/on (false/true)
   again don't result in "set" being called again (although
   PropertyChanged on the underlying object is again called).
2. The device is on (true) before starting the program

   **Result:** The DP Handler is triggered at 
   the start of the program and no change to
   false or true lets it be called again.

What I've tried already for tracking this down is:

1. Implemented a *DummyDebugConverter*.

   Result: I see that it's fired also only once. So giving me no further clue
2. Analyzed the Output Window and found the following message:

   System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=bLightState.Value; DataItem='ControlPanelModel' (HashCode=45596481); target element is 'AdsButton' (Name='btnLight'); target property is 'DeviceState' (type 'Boolean')

   Debugging this didn't give me a clue. My breakpoints e.g. in the debugging converter or the set method never showed me a null-value anywhere. All values in the viewmodel constructor are initialized with default values. But I see the message always just one single time and I assume it relates to the problem somehow.
3. Used the same binding expression for testing purposes on some other elements (a label and a toggle button) besides my usercontrol. They work nicely and are updating their values as expected as soon as the object in the viewmodel changes (desired behaviour). The message in 2 disappers if I remove my usercontrol.

So I come to the conclusion that the error is in my definition of the DP's.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

AdsButton.xaml.cs

```
    [Description("When set to true the device is shown as on"), Category("Default")]
    public bool DeviceState
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(DeviceStateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeviceStateProperty, value); }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty DeviceStateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "DeviceState", typeof(bool),
                typeof(AdsButton), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                  false, 
                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None,
                  DeviceStateChanged, 
                  CoerceDeviceStateProperty,
                  true,
                  UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit));

        private static void DeviceStateChanged(DependencyObject d, 
               DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as AdsButton).DeviceState = (bool) e.NewValue;
        }

        private static object CoerceDeviceStateProperty(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            return value ?? false;
        }
```

ControlPanel.xaml

```
      <src:AdsButton x:Name="btnLight"  
                  Value="{Binding Path=bLight.Value, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                  DeviceState="{Binding Path=bLightState.Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
      <Label Content="{Binding bLightState.Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
      <ToggleButton Content="Button" IsChecked="{Binding bLightState.Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

So does anybody know: Why is my own DP reacting differently from the ones in standard controls?

Comment: You don't need to set DeviceState in DeviceStateChanged method

Comment: Thank you!!! I overlooked this! This has overwritten then binding when being called.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the initial comment by Roger... the answer is obvious:

Setting the DP itself in the setter method overwrites the binding with a fixed value (which effectively removes it), but only if the new value is different from the old one.